# How to Migrate from Athena to "local" Presto +?

Tags: json, amazon-s3, hadoop, amazon-athena, presto

We are currently using Athena with JSON files in S3.  We use all Presto SQL features - our JSON files and corresponding Athena tables have arrays, etc.  What would you recommend for a local stack on Unix?  Install Presto + JSON as local files or Presto + Hadoop/Hive?  Are there any other options? Thank you, -- Alex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Presto + Hive or Presto + Iceberg and here is a tutorial about [Presto + Iceberg](https://ibm.github.io/presto-iceberg-lab/). You should be able to try out different solutions by using Docker first. You can find Presto images [here](https://hub.docker.com/r/prestodb/presto). This way, you can explore the different options quickly. Once you figure out which solution suites you, you can use the deployment instruction here: http://prestodb.io/docs/0.285/installation/deployment.html to deploy the Presto.